# Postgresql connection refused

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to remotely connect to my postgresql database. I have two virtual machines set up both running ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to connect to the second vm using the first vm using

```
psql -h 10.0.1.23 -U postgres -d postgres
```

But I receive the error:

```
Could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "10.0.1.23" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have changed the pg_hba.conf and added

```
host all all 10.0.1.64/24 md5
host all all * md5
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

And changed the postgresql.conf listen_address=" * "

In an attempt to allow all incoming connections. I have also tried to change the firewall settings, but I am unsure of whether or not the ports are properly listening for the connection.

Edit: Output of

```
netstat -an | grep -E '^tcp[^6].*LISTEN'
tcp   0   0 127.0.1.1:53   0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:22     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:631  0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:23     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:5432 0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of running `netstat -an | grep -E '^tcp[^6].*LISTEN'` while PostgreSQL is up and running.

Comment: Server is not listening on 10.0.1.23, only on loopback device (127.0.0.1). But it's late and my brain just stopped.

Comment: So how would I be able to change what the server is listening to?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently I had forgotten to remove the # from listen_address="*". It was a comment the entire time. I am dumb.

Comment: It's alright.  Honest mistake.  We've all done it. :)

Comment: I change configuration for 100 times, restart PG for 100 times and find this :)

Comment: I have worked as a programmer for over 10 years, and today I spent several hours debugging before this answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the `postgresql.conf` file has an entry for`listen_addresses='*'`.  It looks like you are using the wrong configuration parameter name, and might have a space surrounding the asterisk.

Lastly, ensure you restart postgres after making these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Do following

**Update** : `/var/lib/pgsql/<version>/data/postgresql.conf`

**change** : `#listen_addresses = 'localhost' to listen_addresses = '*'`

**restart service**